# How can I change the net-snmp engineID

Tags: linux, freebsd, snmp

I'm using `NET-SNMP 5.7.3` on `Freebsd 12.1`. I want to chane `engineID` with `snmpset` command.

snmpd.conf

```
rwcommunity private
```

I enter this command:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c private localhost e x 800000020109840301
```

The error is:

```
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises
```

I used this command too:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c private localhost 1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.1 x 800000020109840301
```

but this has the above error.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

snmpd.conf

```
engineID a
```

For test:

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost  .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.1.0   

SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING: 80 00 1F 88 04 61
```

Every enginID begins with  `080001F`. It can't change with snmpset. it should set in config file.

Answer (score 1):

From the net-snmp `snmpd.conf` man page:

> The SNMPv3 protocol defines "engineIDs" that uniquely identify an agent. The
>   string must be consistent through time and should not change or conflict 
>   with another agent's engineID. Ever.
>
> Internally, Net-SNMP by default creates a unique engineID that is based off of 
>   the current system time and a random number.  This should be sufficient 
>   for most users unless you're embedding our agent in a device where these numbers won't vary between boxes on the devices initial boot.
>
> EngineIDs are used both as a "context" for selecting information from the device and SNMPv3 with USM uses it to create unique entries for users in its user table.

In other words, changing the engine ID invalidates all existing SNMPv3 user entries and the "context" for information requests, so changing it is a big deal. When changing the engine ID, it has been my experience that you must recreate any existing SNMPv3 users, or else their SNMPv3 passwords stop working. (In other words, the engine ID seems to be used by the SNMPv3 password hashing algorithm.)

I would expect that restarting `snmpd` would be mandatory when changing the engine ID.

The error message tells you that you cannot change the Net-SNMP engine ID using SNMP.

However, you *can* change the engine ID by using the `engineID`, `engineIDType` and/or `engineIDNic` settings in the `snmpd.conf` file, but the man page carries a warning that "you should know what you're doing" if you use them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `-e` and `-E` are the options that change the snmp engineId, as described in snmpd man. How can I use them?

Comment: I don't know: my `man snmpd` does not mention those options at all. Instead, my `man snmpd.conf` suggests that you could add a line `engineID 800000020109840301` to your `snmpd.conf` file to get what you want. Perhaps Debian 10's `net-snmpd 5.7.3+dfsg-5` has been compiled with slightly different options from FreeBSD's one?